# dynamically allocated variable size

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I run this program, output is 4 bytes. ( I use a 64 bit compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *b;
    b=(int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    printf("%d",sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

But shouldn't the output be 40 bytes as I am dynamically allocating 40 bytes of space for 'b'?

Comment: **A pointer is not an array**.

Comment: A pointer is not an array. I got that. But is there any way that I can know how much bytes is allocated to b?

Comment: It prints a size of the pointer itself. (Which is 4 bytes, 32 bits. Are you sure about 64-bit compiler?) There is no (portable and standard) way to get a size of heap-allocated block once it got allocated.

Comment: Btw, don't cast the result of `malloc()` in C, it's only needed in C++.

Comment: You all ready know the size.

Comment: The pointer does not point to an array, but the the first element. Something like `int (*)[length]` is a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

No; it should be the same as `printf("%zu", sizeof(int *));`, which on your implementation is 4, no matter what value you assign to `b`, since `b` has type `int *`, not `int [10]`.